# Como verificar se o usuario entro há 1 hora atrás ou está logado

Tags: php

Estou criando um sistema para verificar se o usuário entrou no site há 1 hora atrás ou antes. Tem uma coluna no banco de dados que fala ultima vez que logou
**Last_Login**(int4)  a data tem que esta nessa formato **ymdHm**(1703221703).

Meu problema é que  eu não sei como posso verificar isso, se ele logou há 1 hora atrás ou antes, ou se ele esta logado.

Meu código que fiz até o momento:

```
    public function check_time(){
    $date = new \DateTime();
    //echo $date->format('ymdHm');
    $conexao = new Config;
    try{
        $conect = $conexao->getConn();
        $prepare = $conect->prepare("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE login = ?");
        $prepare->bindvalue(1, $_SESSION['username']);
        $prepare->execute();
        $dados = $prepare->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if ($prepare->rowCount() >= 1){
            //return $dados['last_login'];
            if($dados['last_login'] == 

        }



    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo "Erro: ".$e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao site Guilherme. Você deseja verificar se o usuário fez login a mais de 1 hora? E se ele tiver feito mas navegou entre várias páginas? Você pretende que isto seja considerado também? Como você é novo, aproveite e dê uma olhada no [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Não so verificar se ele logou a 1hora atras ou antes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vou assumir que você sabe fazer a consulta no banco e pegar o retorno.

Considerando que você guardou o retorno do banco na variável `$retorno`:

```
$zonaTemporal = new \DateTimeZone('America/Sao_Paulo');

$retorno = '201703221525';

$logouEm = \DateTime::createFromFormat('YmdHi', $retorno, $zonaTemporal);

if($logouEm == null) {
  /* Data Inválida no Banco, faz algum tratamento */
}

$intervalo = new \DateInterval('PT1H');

$agora = new \DateTime('now', $zonaTemporal);

$logouEm = $logouEm->add($intervalo);

echo 'Fez o último login em:<br>' . $logouEm->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo '<br>';

echo 'Agora é:<br>' . $agora->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo '<br><br>';


if($logouEm > $agora) {
    echo 'Logou a mais de uma hora';
} else {
    echo 'Ainda não deu uma hora';
}
```

**Nota**: Neste exemplo estou assumindo que as horas estão salvas com a zona temporal brasileira. Isto pode não ser o seu caso. Recomendo que mude a zona temporal para ficar de acordo com o modo que está salvando. Caso você não saiba qual a zona temporal que é salva no banco, é provável que seja o valor default do seu php.ini que geralmente é a mesma zona temporal do computador que está executando o php.

Comment: essa função add($intervalo);  é oque ?

 Call to a member function add() on boolean

Comment: @Guilherme, essa função faz parte do objeto [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) do php. Se você recebeu este erro, é sinal que a sua data está em outro formato, ou ainda, nula. Atualizei o exemplo para ficar mais próximo de como está em seu banco de dados.

Comment: obrigado so mudei o formato funcionou :)

Fez o último login em:
2017-03-22 18:00:00
Agora é:
2017-03-22 17:12:44

Logou a mais de uma hora